I work in Davinci resolve. I have file with multiple audio tracks, but in davinci opens only one audio
So I have a .mkv file with dubs and subs, I can import it in Davinci resolve, but works only the one track. I used HD Video Converter Factory Pro for conversion in .mp4 with multiple tracks and it works fine. So what script I should use for the same result? I tried many scripts, but they didn't work properly at all.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
